# Angular 4 unit test service calling http service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a service that is calling a http function:

```
processLogin(info) {
    return this._call.post('login', info).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
            this._auth.login(response.object);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }, error => {
        return false;
    });
}
```

And this is the test I'm trying to make:

```
describe('Facebook Login', () => {
    let service: FacebookLoginService;
    let call: CallService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                FacebookLoginService,
                { provide: CallService, useClass: CallServiceMock },
            ]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(FacebookLoginService);
        call = TestBed.get(CallService);
    });

    it('should process the login when the post method return success', () => {
        spyOn(call, 'post').and.returnValue(Observable.of({status: 'success'}));

        service.processLogin('any').subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I run the test I keep getting the error message

> processLogin().subscribe( ... ) is not a function

And if I change the type of response mocked to anything but `Observable.of`, I get the error message

> call.post.subscribe( ... ) is not a function

Why is it not wokirng? I have a very similar test on another service that also calls `call.post()` and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processLogin` returns not an observable but a subscription, so there will be no `subscribe` method on it. Returned values in `subscribe` callbacks are ignored, so `processLogin` won't work as expected.

It likely should be changed to return an observable instead:

```
return this._call.post('login', info).map(response => { ... });
```

Then it can be tested like:

```
spyOn(_call, 'post').and.returnValue(Observable.of({ status: 'success' }));

const login$ = service.processLogin('any');
expect(_call).toHaveBeenCalledWith('login', 'any');

login$.subscribe(response => {
  expect(response).toBe(...);
}, err => { throw err });
```

It will also need to mock `_auth`.

Comment: With those changes the test now has the subscribe method, but the actual `processLogin` method never execute. I think it's because it's missing the `subscribe()`.

Comment: It's subscribed with login$.subscribe in test. If you mean that it doesn't work as expected in the app, then yes, you need add `subscribe` wherever you use it.

Comment: I just don't understand how to make it work. Because if I don't use `.subscribe()` the method never execute. But if I do, then the test is going to fail, as you explained in the answer. What changes should I made to the method in order to keep both working?

Comment: You need to replace `subscribe` word in `processLogin` method with `map` word. Then you need to make sure that you added `subscribe(...)` to every place where you use `processLogin` in your app, because it is cold observable.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. I was thinking that it has anything to do with the own method. I get it. Now it's working. Thanks!